# Powershell to control external Windows Devices

Tags: powershell, windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode scanner **Motorola MC9090** that I connect to my PC **(Win10 64-bit)** via USB. 
I have a Windows Mobile Device Center installed that recognizes this device just fine and I can do all I need to do via GUI.

I would like to write a PS script to copy some files from my PC to the device.
The device in Win Explorer is called **`"WindowsCE"`** and one of the folders on the device is **`"Application"`**. I tried all I know to be able to see the device in powershell but no luck... `Start WindowsCE\Application` did not work...

When I run this `Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName WindowsCE -PresentOnly` I get the device name when scanner is connected to my PC so I know Powershell can "see" it but I don't know how to control the device.

Please help!

Thanks,

Aberforth!

Comment: You might have luck looking for how you'd control the device with C# or the .Net Framework.  Any code that works for that can almost certainly be ported to PowerShell.  There does appear to be [a .Net developer kit](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile-computers/handheld/mc9090-wm.html).

Comment: Problem here is that I am running on corporate machine and cannot install anything external. That's why I'm looking for more "direct" approach...

Comment: If you can't install anything, you're probably stuck. To do it without vendor tools, you'd probably have to use [RAPI or RAPI2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee497054(v=winembedded.60).aspx).

Comment: When its connected and the software is open does it show up as an actual drive in windows or just in the app? You could use PS to launch the software if it generates the windows drive. You could also potentially use com objects to push buttons and stuff for you via powershell.

Comment: @Sambardo - When scanner is connected to my PC it shows as "Device" right next to C:\ drive and it's called WindowsCE. I tried to navigate to this device on powershell `Start WindowsCe\Applications` but error says that path cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

So I can filter down to which device is plugged in but I cant really get any further:

```
$test = Get-Pnpdevice

($test | where Name -eq 'WindowsCE') | Format-list
```

This will display all the information about WindowCE devices but now you can filter it to if its plugged in.

```
($test | where Name -eq 'WindowsCE') | where Present -eq 'True'
```

Not sure if it helps but thats as far as I can get.  I wish we could transfer files without using the Windows Mobile application.  Good Luck.